# Are you allowed to have a standalone version of your Steam game?

Tags: steam, steamworks

My game is on Steam since a few years. Now I also want to make a standalone version of it, because a few players asked for it.

I looked for the Steam Distribution Agreement, but I couldn't find it. Also Google didn't help with the research.

So, is it allowed to have a standalone version of your Steam game? E.g. obtainable from your own website.

Comment: This sounds like a question to direct to Valve. Hearsay from strangers on the Internet like us will not constitute a legal defense if you're worried about being pursued for breach of contract.

Comment: `This sounds like a question to direct to Valve` Either this, or reading all agreements/contracts between you and valve. Or ask a lawyer to read them for you. Either way, us saying yes or no doesn't protect you at all.

Comment: Unless something had changed, the agreement states that there is no exclusivity required to publish on steam and that you are free to publish your game anywhere else as long as you don't make the steam version more expensive than any other version. But as stated before, ask valve directly.